# EF generates wrong query, causing exception: Must declare the scalar variable '@...'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.3, and below is my code (BTW, the RealPrice field of the gift table is of decimal type):

```
var filters = new StringBuilder();
var parameters = new List<object>();

decimal numRealPrice = 25.00m;
filters.Append("RealPrice = @RealPrice");
var paramRealPrice = new SqlParameter("@RealPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal);
paramRealPrice.Value = numRealPrice;
parameters.Add(numRealPrice);

string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM gift WHERE ";

sqlStatement = sqlStatement + filters;

List<OM_Gift_BO> gifts = this.objEntity.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Gift_BO>(sqlStatement, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();

//....
```

And the framework somewhat generated a SQL query(according to Express profiler 2.0):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM gift WHERE RealPrice = @RealPrice',N'@p0 decimal(4,2)',@p0=25.00
go
```

I have no idea where does the name 'p0' come from, however, since it is different from RealPrice, I got an exception saying:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@RealPrice".

Well, this method works OK with string type parameters.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `@p0` is a parameter that EF creates to support your `WHERE` clause. I don't know why you are trying to use EF this way.

Comment: The point is: if it is Int/Varchar/Nvarchar type instead of Decimal, then it will be `@RealPrice`, instead of `@p0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your assigning `numRealPrice` directly to your `parameters` and passing that directly to ExecuteStoreQuery

Replace

```
parameters.Add(numRealPrice);
```

With

```
parameters.Add(paramRealPrice);
```

---

Additionally I'm not sure if its of any value, as it depends on what your trying to achieve, however you could probably shorten your code as follows

```
var statement = "SELECT * FROM gift WHERE RealPrice = {0}";
var gifts = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<OM_Gift_BO>(statment, numRealPrice).ToList();
```